# Electron : Net from Nodejs doesn't trigger events on Windows build

Tags: node.js, electron

I created a port scanner function using the module Net from Nodejs but the function doesn't work on my windows build.
I have no error, I just don't have any trigger from the events functions.
It's work perfectly in my Webstorm (on MacOS).
Does somebody have an idea of the roots causes ?
PS : I have nodeIntegration enable.
Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

[As per the doc said](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net) :-

> On Windows, the local domain is implemented using a named pipe. The
>   path must refer to an entry in \?\pipe\ or \.\pipe. Any characters
>   are permitted, but the latter may do some processing of pipe names,
>   such as resolving .. sequences

JavaScript string escaping requires paths to be specified with extra backslash escaping such as:

```
net.createServer().listen(
  path.join('\\\\?\\pipe', process.cwd(), 'myctl'));
```

Try it hope it would help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer !
I think it's a good start, I'm managing to make it work but for the moment I'm a bit lost !
I will keep you informed.